# How to modify android kernel without building them from source?

Tags: android, kernel

I am trying to modify android kernel without any source because out device Micromax a106 does not have any source by oem. I've searched on google but didn't find the desired result. I have good programming skills and i can give my time in reading the sources inside my device kernel. If anyone knows the process please share with me, i need it hardly. Thank you all.

Comment: The kernel is a part of the Android OS. So you have to modify the kernel-code of the source and run it on your device. Find the stock software and modify it, and deploy your version.

Comment: you can download android open source project from git hub and you can go through the code itself

Comment: thank you Lunar & Hanuman sir